# Adding a Bookmark Table in a Document

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, bookmarks

I've got many places I'd like to Bookmark in Word and I'd like to create a Table for all these bookmarks, like a Table Of Contents, but for Bookmarks. For instance :

---

On page 5 in my Word Document :

[MyPlace 1]

Some text about MyPlace 1

On page 8 in my Word Document :

[MyPlace 2]

Some text about MyPlace 2. This is some other text about MyPlace 2

---

I've added Bookmarks around each one of my [MyPlace #]. Now I want to create a Table that will show the bookmarks like so :

[MyPlace 1].......................................5

[Myplace 2].......................................8

And I want this table to be updated (such as an update with F9), whenever I change the name of the Bookmark, or its page.

I don't want the text of the content of the bookmark to be a part of said bookmark.

I've tryed using { TOC \b "something" }. But I don't know what to put into "something" to get all the bookmarks in one table

Answer (score 0):

#### I'd like to create a Table for bookmarks, like a Table Of Contents, but for Bookmarks

> To add a table of contents for an individual section, you create a
>   bookmark for that section and specify that bookmark in the TOC field
>   code.
>
> **Add the bookmarks**
>
> 1. Select the section that you want to create a table of contents for.
> 2. On the Insert tab, in the Links group, click Bookmark.
>
>    [image]
> 3. In the Bookmark name box, type a name for the bookmark.
>
>    Note    Use a name that’s easy to remember, such as section1.
> 4. Click Add.
> 5. Repeat steps 1-4 for each section that you want to add a table of contents to.
>
> **Create the tables of contents**
>
> 1. Click where you want to add a section table of contents.
> 2. On the Insert tab, in the Text group, click Quick Parts, and then click Field.
>
>    [image]
> 3. Under Field names, click TOC.
> 4. Click Field Codes, and then click Options.
> 5. In the Switches list, click \b, click Add to Field, and then click OK.
> 6. In the Field codes box, type the name of the bookmark for that section.
>
>    Important   Be sure that a space separates the \b switch and the bookmark name.
> 7. Click OK.
> 8. Repeat steps 1-7 for each section TOC that you want to add to your document.

Source [Add a table of contents for each section](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Add-a-table-of-contents-for-each-section-1d4fcb55-3ef5-4999-b068-85f9eb1bef9c)

Comment: Thanks, but this does not answer completely my question. I need an automatic solution. Yours says I need to repeat the actions for every bookmark I want to have in my bookmark table. Plus, but maybe I do it wrong, at the end, it says that no entry has been found. Even though I put a bookmark name. So I think it does not work

Comment: You want an automated bookmark table? In that case you need to write some (VBA) script. Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/848097/edit) with your new requirements.

Comment: I don't want any VBA in my solution. Maybe it is not feasible.